# I am having trouble centering a label in Xcode 8.1.

Tags: ios, xcode

The main problem is that I tried command+drag to the view and selecting "align horizontally in the container", but for some reason(I was doing this on the iPhone 7) when I checked the other devices(such as the iPad Pro) they were not aligned. Then I tried adding constraints, which also did not work. My question is how in the world do you center a label without using Swift?

Comment: Use autolayouts and set it center in storyboard. What's the issue in that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing first: "Center Horizontally in Container" *is* a constraint.

My initial guess is that you’ve neglected some sort of ambiguity or possibly created a constraint which conflicts with (and overrides) the centering constraint. If this is the case, you should see warnings telling you what the problem is.

As long as there's no vertical ambiguity, and no conflicting horizontal constraints (leading/trailing space), your label should be centered—no Swift code necessary.

I get the impression that you’re fairly new to Xcode, so if you don’t know already, you can check the existing constraints on an object in [the Size Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zjw4K.png), denoted by the ruler in the right sidebar. It’s quite possible that there’s an old constraint you forgot to remove, or one you added but don’t need.

Another thing to note: I’ve experienced some layout issues when switching devices in the new Interface Builder in Xcode 8—it’s just a bit buggy in my experience, especially with regard to Stack Views. If you have doubts about how something looks, I’d recommend running the app in Simulator for some devices you don’t have on hand to check it out.

Comment: I finally found out how to center a label(after 3 hours)!I really appreciate your response, and thanks a lot.

Comment: @tj75467 Good to hear! If it wasn't my answer that helped, I recommend posting your own answer with what you had to change to make it work. That way, if someone stumbles across this question, they can hopefully get something useful out of it.